# Database multiple database query each time

Tags: database, sql, query

I'm writing a rest service. For each request I use about 4-8 queries.

Should I try to refactor those into a single query?

Comment: Some options here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336362/execute-multiple-sql-commands-in-one-round-trip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It very much depends on the data.

However what you really really want to avoid is getting a number of rows from one query and then for each row firing of a second query for each row returned. In this situation a single join query will perform an order of magnitude faster than several individual queries.